# Xubuntu Open settings from terminal?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

How can I open the settings menu from bash on Xubuntu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main settings panel is

```
xfce4-settings-manager
```

but, if you want to open specific settings dialog there are other commands to help you. Like

```
xfce4-mime-settings (opens mime editor)
xfce4-session-settings (startup/auto-start settings)
xfce4-accessibility-settings 
xfce4-mouse-settings
xfce4-settings-editor
xfce4-appearance-settings
xfce4-notes-settings          
xfce4-notifyd-config (notification settings)
xfce4-clipman-settings (default clip manager's)
xfce4-power-manager-settings
xfce4-display-settings
xfce4-keyboard-settings
```

Other settings purpose can be easily derived from name.

Answer (score 0):

This should launch it:

```
xfce4-settings
```

If that doesn't work, it's one of the following:

```
xfce4-settings-manager
xfce-mcs-manager
```

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1087272

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xfce4